# Statistic for test of significant difference between 3 spatial distributions

Tags: spatial-statistics, statistics

I have three spatial averages of Particulate matter over a certain area as seen below.

[image]

There clearly seems to be a difference between average PM concentrations for each of these months, but how can I statistically say that there exists a significant difference between the three?

Comment: This may be a question for https://stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I think it could be answered in either

Comment: In the past I have used SAGA for a similar sort of task. I ran it in QGIS and for this I believe you could use Multiple Regression Analysis (Raster/Raster) if you concentration layers are in that form?

Comment: This is a complex subject but there is some good information available. I would start with the widely-cited paper by Anselin et al (2006) which is freely available here: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.0016-7363.2005.00671.x. See also the free program called Geoda which arises from Anselin's work and available here: https://geodacenter.github.io/. The latter site has lots of infomation available as downloadable pdf files.